# Como lanzar activity mediante una notificacion, cuando el dispositivo esta bloqueado(Apagado la pantalla)?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, push-notification

Tengo una aplicacion la cual necesito lanzar un activity de tipo llamada(timbre), el problema esque cuando el dispositivo esta bloqueado no se lanza la actividad, en cualquier otra situacion si lo lanza...
Mi codigo para realizar esa funcion es esta:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getData()!=null) {
        //Log.d("WILSON", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        Map<String,String> data=new HashMap<>();
        String customer=data.get("customer");
        String lat=data.get("lat");
        String lng=data.get("lng");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CustommerCall.class);
        intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
        intent.putExtra("lng", lng);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Pero como decia anteriormente me funciona en cualquier situacion, menos cuando el dispositivo esta bloqueado.... Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1):

No puedes mostrar un activity desde la pantalla de blockeo, lo que recomiendo es que muestres una **notificacion** y al ser presionada abra la pantalla que quieres mostrar

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CustommerCall.class);
intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
intent.putExtra("lng", lng);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("Mi aplicacion")
        .setContentText("La alarma se ha activado, por favor presiona aqui para ver la informacion");

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Ahora que si lo que deseas es crear una nueva pantalla de llamada, lo que quieres hacer es muy diferente, te recomiendo ver como crear una aplicacion que administre y cree llamadas